# Joining Queries Into Functioning As One

Tags: postgresql

I have two queries that return different results, and I would like to merge them but I'm still learning how to write in postgreSQ, so I', having some trouble doing this. My queries are:

1. This one returns a list of all the months until the present one.

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2019-01-01', now(), '1 month')

EXAMPLE:

    generate_series 
------------------------ 
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00
2019-02-01 00:00:00+00
2019-03-01 00:00:00+00
2019-04-01 00:00:00+00
```

2. This one returns a count of how many people signed up during that month. But this one is only returning the ones where months are not zero.

```
SELECT date_trunc('MONTH', (date_signed_up::date)) AS monthly, count(id) AS count FROM customer 
WHERE group_id = 1
GROUP BY monthly
ORDER BY monthly asc

EXAMPLE:

     monthly           | count
-----------------------------------
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00 |   3
2019-02-01 00:00:00+00 |   1
2019-04-01 00:00:00+00 |   1
```

The expected result or what I need is to have a table like this:

```
     monthly           | count
-----------------------------------
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00 |   3
2019-02-01 00:00:00+00 |   1
2019-03-01 00:00:00+00 |   0
2019-04-01 00:00:00+00 |   1
2019-05-01 00:00:00+00 |   0

..etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT period monthly, count(id) count 
    FROM generate_series('2019-01-01', now(), '1 month') p (period)
        LEFT JOIN customer 
            ON p.period = date_trunc('MONTH', (date_signed_up::date)) AND group_id = 1
    GROUP BY monthly
    ORDER BY monthly asc
```

Comment: Thank you! This didn't gave me all the months, but I just moved the where statement to the LEFT JOIN and it worked, so thank you for your help!!

Comment: Right. No group id in the missing rows. I'll update the answer for the next person who stops by.